# ionauth login maximum attempts implementation

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, captcha, ion-auth

I have just started using **ionauth**, and I am trying to implement the maximum login attempts feature.

Problem is, I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this function on [the documentation](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/).

I figured out the function to call to check if maximum login attempts exceeded was this

```
$this->ion_auth->is_max_login_attempts_exceeded()
```

I'd like to know what protection to do if login attempts are exceeded?

```
<ul>
 <li>block the user for a specific time?</li>
 <li>enforce a captcha?</li>
 <li>both?</li>
</ul>
```

And if he enter a correct captcha (assuming I enforce captcha) or if the time runs out (assuming I stop login attempts for a specific time), how do I allow login's again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on the design of your project, if it's some store or paid services provider, than you can think of implementing this and disallowing user to login for a minute or two, if it's your personal blog, I would suggest you not to implement this at all.

To force clear the attempts, if you need to, you can call

```
$this->ion_auth->clear_login_attempts($identity);
```

and to block user from trying to log in, you can make an if statement

```
if(!is_max_login_attempts_exceeded($identity)) {
    // try to login
}
```

If you want to implement a captcha, you can change the if statement above to check if the captcha input was correct and use the code block above to make a decision whether to show captcha in your login form.

In any case, don't bother implementing this if you've never got brute forced before and if the information/actions that can be gathered/run by the hacker are not dangerous enough as it will simply annoy those, who simply forgot their password and try every password they have ever used before.